# Using data from same mysql table in the query

Tags: mysql

I have found a little strange problem. Here is the query:

```
SELECT *, @allaccts := TRIM( BOTH  ',' FROM owneridslinked4billing) as 
 targetids, ( select sum(price) from orderstable where 
   paymentstatus='unpaid' and ownid in (@allaccts) ) as amountdue FROM users
```

The problem is that the output of targetids is:

```
110909,110910,110911,110912
```

(exactly what is required)

But the query is outputting wrong results. It is not including all ids (110909,110910,110911,110912) in the query "and ownid in (@allaccts)". I guess it is taking all comma separated value as one instead of separate values so outputting wrong results.

I hope it makes sense.

All I want is to ask mysql to use the data from `owneridslinked4billing` field in the query and output the result where `ownid` is in `owneridslinked4billing` (which is a comma separated list of ids).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `FIND_IN_SET` might offer an immediate fix here:

```
SELECT *, @allaccts := TRIM( BOTH ',' FROM owneridslinked4billing) as targetids,
    ( select sum(price) from orderstable
      where paymentstatus='unpaid' and
      FIND_IN_SET(ownid, @allaccts) > 0 ) as amountdue
FROM users;
```

This would work assuming that your intention is to find a `ownid` value in the CSV list of all accounts `110909,110910,110911,110912`.

Moving forward, you should avoid `FIND_IN_SET` and CSV data in general, and normalize your data.  Move each id to a separate row and do a join.

Comment: This solved it, thanks. But I still wonder why IN did not work here? :)

Comment: @HaiderAbbas `IN` works with a list of _columns_, not a CSV list of values.